# Writing map reduce in hadoop HDInsight with piping and bash scripts

Tags: bash, python-3.x, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to do a map reduce job in hadoop streaming, HDInsight. The way I approached it is that I have a mapper that pipes many other scripts (both bash and python) I created to eventually come out with the key\tvalue options. I am copying all the files to all the nodes as expected. However, I keep getting the error shown below. What could be the reason - is piping in bash a problem?

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
```

Comment: Hadoop streaming is a glorified pipe... You should break the jobs into multiple mapreduce tasks. You should also look at the actual failed attempt logs in the YARN UI

Comment: Alternatively, you can try using MrJob library of Python instead